# Create a NMARoute object from json file without additional HTTP call

Tags: ios, here-api

We want to create a NMARoute without calling [NMACoreRouter calculateRouteWithStops: ...] as it send an unnecessary HTTP call to here.com. Because we already have every information to create a NMARoute object, we just want to initialize it. Unfortunately there is no public initializer. Is there any other approach to initialize a NMARoute object?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at route serialization:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics/route-serialization.html

Basically, the gist of it is that you can create a route based on an NSData object:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmaroute.html#topic-apiref__routefromserializedroute-colon-error-colon

Note:

The route data depends directly on the map data on your device. The routing data can become obsolete with a map update, and deserialization may not be valid.